# c++ how to initialize const elements of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, constants

i need a way to initialize const elements of an array for the program i am currently working on.
The problem is that i have to initialize these elements with a function, there is no way to do it like this:

```
const int array[255] = {1, 1278632, 188, ...};
```

because its alot of data i have to generate.
What i tried is to *memcpy* data to the const int's but that can't work and hasn't worked.

```
 const int array[255];

 void generateData(){
      for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
          initializeSomehowTo(5, array[i]);
      }
 }
```

I hope you understand what i am trying, sorry if i doubled the question, i must have overlooked it.

Comment: You can't do `const int array[255] = initializeMyArray()`, but if you used `std::array`, you could do `const std::array<int, 255> = initializeMyArray()`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about this?

```
#include <array>
typedef std::array<int, 255> Array;

const Array array = generateData();

Array generateData(){
    Array a;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        initializeSomehowTo(a[i]);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: this works great, only thing is that **const int array[10][10][10];** looks really scary: **const std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10>, 10> Array;** ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest approach is to get the filled array from a function and use that to initialize your `const` (or `constexpr`) object. However, built-in arrays can't be copied but `std::array<T, N>` be:

```
std::array<T, 255> array = initializeData();
```

If you need a built-in array, I can imagine initializing a `static` member of a class (template, actually) where the index is expanded from indices expanded from an `std::make_index_sequence<255>` and used as positional argument in the array, i.e., something along these lines:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

int some_function(std::size_t i) { return i; }

template <typename> struct initialized_array_base;
template <std::size_t... I>
struct initialized_array_base<std::index_sequence<I...>> {
    static const int array[sizeof...(I)];
};

template <std::size_t... I>
int const initialized_array_base<std::index_sequence<I...>>::array[sizeof...(I)]
    = { some_function(I)... };

struct initialized_array
    :initialized_array_base<std::make_index_sequence<256>> {
};

int main() {
    std::copy(std::begin(initialized_array::array),
              std::end(initialized_array::array),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Wow that looks scary for such a simple task ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a writable array, initialize it, and, then, create a const reference to it.

```
int arry[255];

void generateData(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
      initializeSomehowTo(5, arry[i]);
  }
}

const int (&array)[255] = arry;
```

Comment: This does not stop `arry` from getting modified, right?

Comment: I think you can also std::static_cast to a const reference

Comment: An extra level of indirection (for the reference variable that also has static storage) may not optimize away.  **I would definitely recommend not using this**, since returning a `std::array<>` from an initializer function avoids any performance downside.